# android: how to scroll continuously updating text

Tags: android

I am developing an app in android in which, I have to scroll the time of different cities on the bottom horizontally. At the single time, I can get the local time of those cities and show them in horizontally scrolling text. Moreover, I can get the time of every single update of minute and update the entire textview. But, how to update that time in continuously scrolling text???
The below is the example of what I want to do

http://www.itfseafarers.org/ look at the topmost black strip...it updates the time automatically after every minute,and string moves continuously without being started from beginning.